# UI - Vote up/down not highlighting

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Has anyone else seen this happening?  As of yesterday, when you voted up or down the site would highlight your vote.  As of this morning, the vote count changes as expected but no hightlighting.

I'm running IE8, Win7Pro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a whiteboard ink shortage, so we couldn't fill the arrows for a few hours.

Santa brought some new markers, so everything's well again.